# Pythonic Classes and the Zen of Python

Tags: python, class, python-dataclasses

The Zen of Python says:

*“There should be one—and preferably only one—obvious way to do it.”*

Let’s say I want to create a class that builds a financial transaction. The class should allow the user to build a transaction and then call a `sign()` method to sign the transaction in preparation for it to be broadcast via an API call.

The class will have the following parameters:

```
sender
recipient
amount
signer (private key for signing)
metadata
signed_data
```

All of these are strings, except for the amount which is an int, and all are required except for the last two: metadata which is an optional parameter, and signed_data which is created when the method `sign()` is called.

We would like all of the parameters to undergo some kind of validation before the signing happens so we can reject badly formatted transactions by raising an appropriate error for the user.

This seems straight-forward using a classic Python class and constructor:

```
class Transaction:
    def __init__(self, sender, recipient, amount, signer, metadata=None):
            self.sender = sender
            self.recipient = recipient
            self.amount = amount
            self.signer = signer

            if metadata:
                self.metadata = metadata

    def is_valid(self):
        # check that all required parameters are valid and exist and return True, 
        # otherwise return false

    def sign(self):
        if self.is_valid():
            # sign transaction
            self.signed_data = "pretend signature"
        else:
            # raise InvalidTransactionError
```

Or with properties:

```
class Transaction:
    def __init__(self, sender, recipient, amount, signer, metadata=None):
        self._sender = sender
        self._recipient = recipient
        self._amount = amount
        self._signer = signer
        self._signed_data = None

        if metadata:
            self._metadata = metadata

    @property
    def sender(self):
        return self._sender

    @sender.setter
    def sender(self, sender):
        # validate value, raise InvalidParamError if invalid
        self._sender = sender

    @property
    def recipient(self):
        return self._recipient

    @recipient.setter
    def recipient(self, recipient):
        # validate value, raise InvalidParamError if invalid
        self._recipient = recipient

    @property
    def amount(self):
        return self._amount

    @amount.setter
    def amount(self, amount):
        # validate value, raise InvalidParamError if invalid
        self._amount = amount

    @property
    def signer(self):
        return self._signer

    @signer.setter
    def signer(self, signer):
        # validate value, raise InvalidParamError if invalid
        self._signer = signer

    @property
    def metadata(self):
        return self._metadata

    @metadata.setter
    def metadata(self, metadata):
        # validate value, raise InvalidParamError if invalid
        self._metadata = metadata

    @property
    def signed_data(self):
        return self._signed_data

    @signed_data.setter
    def signed_data(self, signed_data):
        # validate value, raise InvalidParamError if invalid
        self._signed_data = signed_data

    def is_valid(self):
        return (self.sender and self.recipient and self.amount and self.signer)

    def sign(self):
        if self.is_valid():
            # sign transaction
            self.signed_data = "pretend signature"
        else:
            # raise InvalidTransactionError
            print("Invalid Transaction!")
```

We can now validate each value when it’s set so by the time we go to sign we know we have valid parameters and the `is_valid()` method only has to check that all required parameters have been set. This feels a little more Pythonic to me than doing all the validation in the single `is_valid()` method but I am unsure if all the extra boiler plate code is really worth it.

With dataclasses:

```
@dataclass
class Transaction:
    sender: str
    recipient: str
    amount: int
    signer: str
    metadata: str = None
    signed_data: str = None

    def is_valid(self):
        # check that all parameters are valid and exist and return True, 
        # otherwise return false

    def sign(self):
        if self.is_valid():
            # sign transaction
            self.signed_data = "pretend signature"
        else:
            # raise InvalidTransactionError
            print("Invalid Transaction!")
```

Comparing this to Approach

1, this is pretty nice. It’s concise, clean, and readable and already has `__init__()`, `__repr__()` and `__eq__()` methods built-in. On the other hand, compared to Approach

2 we’re back to validating all the inputs via a massive `is_valid()` method.

We could try to use properties with dataclasses but that's actually harder than it sounds. According to [this blog post](https://blog.florimond.dev/reconciling-dataclasses-and-properties-in-python) it can be done something like this:

```
@dataclass
class Transaction:
    sender: str
    _sender: field(init=False, repr=False)
    recipient: str
    _recipient: field(init=False, repr=False)
   . . .
   # properties for all parameters

    def is_valid(self):
        # if all parameters exist, return True, 
        # otherwise return false

    def sign(self):
        if self.is_valid():
            # sign transaction
            self.signed_data = "pretend signature"
        else:
            # raise InvalidTransactionError
            print("Invalid Transaction!")
```

Is there one and only one obvious way to do this? Are dataclasses recommended for this kind of application?

Comment: Let see what folks will say, but in my understanding `dataclasses` are better used as parent class. To make a nicely based class easy to read that can be used as template.

Comment: It's not clear why you allow assignment to these attributes at all.

Comment: @user2357112, that's a good point. I guess in my mind I was leaving the possibility of default values in the constructor so the user doesn't have to initialize with a long constructor but can do something like this:

tx = Transction()
tx.sender = "me"
tx.recipient = "you"
....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, and not limited to Python, it is a good idea to write code which "[fails fast](https://www.martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/failFast.pdf)": that is, if something goes wrong at runtime, you want it to be detected and signalled (e.g. by throwing an exception) as early as possible.

Especially in the context of debugging, if the bug is that an invalid value is being set, you want the exception to be thrown at the time the value is set, so that the stack trace includes the method setting the invalid value. If the exception is thrown at the time the value is used, then you can't signal which part of the code caused the invalid value.

Of your three examples, only the second one allows you to follow this principle. It may require more boilerplate code, but writing boilerplate code is easy and doesn't take much time, compared to debugging without a meaningful stack trace.

By the way, if you have setters which do validation, then you should call these setters from your constructor too, otherwise it's possible to create an object with an invalid initial state.

Answer (score 2):

Given your constraints, I think your `dataclass` approach can be improved to produce an expressive and idiomatic solution with very strong runtime assertions about the resulting `Transaction` instances, mostly by leveraging the [`__post_init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing) mechanism:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict, field
from typing import Optional

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Transaction:
    sender: str
    recipient: str
    amount: int
    signer: str
    metadata: Optional[str] = None
    signed_data: str = field(init=False)

    def is_valid(self) -> bool:
        ...  # implement your validity assertion logic

    def __post_init__(self):
        if self.is_valid():
            object.__setattr__(self, "signed_data", "pretend signature")
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid transaction with parameter list "
                             f"{asdict(self)}.")
```

This reduces the amount of code you have to maintain and understand to a degree where every written line relates to a meaningful part of your requirements, which is the essence of pythonic code.

Put into words, instances of this `Transaction` class may specify `metadata` but don't need to and may not supply their own `signed_data`, something which was possible in your variant #3. Attributes can't be mutated any more after initialization (enforced by `frozen=True`), so that an instance that is valid cannot be altered into an invalid state. And most importantly, since the validation is now part of the constructor, it is impossible for an invalid instance to exist. Whenever you are able to refer to a `Transaction` in runtime, you can be 100% sure that it passed the validity check and would do so again.

Since you based your question on python-zen conformity (referring to *Beautiful is better than ugly* and *Simple is better than complex* in particular), I'd say this solution is preferable to the `property` based one.